# Read printable string from AttributeTypeAndValue using BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

Trying to read string from `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Crmf.AttributeTypeAndValue`.
The string value read from the `AttributeTypeAndValue` contains the junk value in the beginning.

My code:

```
//create type value
string id = "1.2";
string value = "hello";
var derValue = new DerPrintableString(value);
var typeValue = new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Crmf.AttributeTypeAndValue(id, derValue);

//read type value
var decodedValue = new DerPrintableString(typeValue.Value.GetDerEncoded());
Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}, Decoded: {1}", 
            derValue.GetString(), decodedValue.GetString());
```

The output for above code is,
[image]

Please help me extract the original string value from AttributeTypeAndValue without junk characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem is with,

```
var decodedValue = new DerPrintableString(typeValue.Value.GetDerEncoded());
```

Changing it to the following helped me extract the string without junk value,

```
var decodedValue = DerPrintableString.GetInstance(typeValue.Value);
```