# Extract Template Id from a certificate

Tags: java, certificate

I got a base64 encoded client certificate and I need to read out the Template ID from the certificate. Anyone who could help me in the right direction of what classes to use etc?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer which shows an example using BouncyCastle

[Read printable string from AttributeTypeAndValue using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888143/read-printable-string-from-attributetypeandvalue-using-bouncycastle)